# Multi child processes from Node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork, child-process

I have a requirement where the main Node js application would have to fork (/create) a js file multiple times and keep it running for atleast an hour. I understand that each of the child processes have their own memory space, PID, and execution time. However, I am expecting a spike in the number of such child processes. I see that the number is limited to the number of CPU cores. The number of child process that is getting created is limited to the number of cores post which the forking is not working.

My application is on AWS EBS c4.2xlarge which has 4 processors with 2 cores per socket - basically 8 cores. So, the number of child process is limited to number of cores. How do I do this?

Here is the code:

```
var args=[id, name];
var monitor = cp.fork('services/collect.js', args);
monitor.send('10');
proc.push(monitor);
```

Please help.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Where exactly do you see that the number of `child_processes` you can create is limited to the amount of cores? - Because that's not the case. You can create as many child_processes as you want until you exhaust your server's resources

Comment: In my case, the 9th child is not getting forked..

Comment: Something else is your problem - Can't really help deduce what - but you are not limited on the number of child-processes in the way you say you are

Comment: What you are saying is akin to: 'I have a dual-core PC hence I can only be running 2 applications at a time'